# Mongoengine query by reference list

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have 2 classes (I am using Flask-mongoengine):

```
class ArticleCategory(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField(verbose_name='Title', required=True, unique=True)
    desc = db.StringField(verbose_name='Slug', required=True)

class Article(CreateUpdateMixin, DeletedMixin, db.Document):
    title = db.StringField(verbose_name='Title', required=True)
    slug = db.StringField(verbose_name='Slug', required=True, unique=True)
    content = db.StringField(verbose_name='Content', required=True)
    #Many-to-many relation
    categories = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField(ArticleCategory),
                              verbose_name='Category', required=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

For now I want to get all articles by specific category (or category's name). I cannot find operator like `__eq` in mongoengine querying help.

Operator like `Article.objects(categories__in('some_category'))` failed.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong query, see documentation http://mongoengine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/querying.html#query-operators.

```
Article.objects(categories__in=['ARTICLE_CATEGORY_ID'])
```